# How to get the latest offset of kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

I want to use kafka+spark streaming to build a application, the app will receive data of mutilpe topics. I wnat to use the method

```
def createDirectStream[
K: ClassTag,
V: ClassTag,
KD <: Decoder[K]: ClassTag,
VD <: Decoder[V]: ClassTag,
R: ClassTag] (
  ssc: StreamingContext,
  kafkaParams: Map[String, String],
  fromOffsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long],
  messageHandler: MessageAndMetadata[K, V] => R
)
```

which will emit topic+message, but in the beginning, I need to pass the fromOffsets parameter to this func. Now the question is that I do not know the latest offset of the topics, what should I do to get it so that I can pass the offset to the func. Assume no message is in the kafka yet.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no messages in Kafka yet, then offsets for each partition are at 0. If you want to start out without offsets, you can use the overload which doesn't take the `fromOffsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long]` parameter:

```
def createDirectStream[
  K: ClassTag,
  V: ClassTag,
  KD <: Decoder[K]: ClassTag,
  VD <: Decoder[V]: ClassTag](
    ssc: StreamingContext,
    kafkaParams: Map[String, String],
    topics: Set[String]
)
```

When you start running the Streaming job, you can extract the offsets by casting the `RDD` to `HasOffsetRanges`:

```
inputDStream.transform {
  rdd => 
    val offsets = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges]
    // Save offsets
}
```